# php read a line from file and save pointer of next line for next execution of script

Tags: php

I am reading file line by

```
$handle = fopen("foo.txt", "r" );
$line = fgets($handle);
```

I want to read a single line in each execution of script and in next execution i want to read next line instead which is read by previous execution.

Is there any way i can save current pointer of file so that next time instead of reading file from the beginning it can be started from the pointed value of pointer ?

I can do it via storing pointer value in session but script can be executed by multiple sessions so it fails. i want a universal way which doesn't depends on session just like storing pointer value in memory which could be read by any user session.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to save the number of bytes read into a text file (or database) and use fseek to relocate to your position you are looking for.
Check out the [PHP manual for fseek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) and you should be able to quickly setup something to:

1. open the file
2. open the storage file
3. seek to the location in the storage file
4. read the new line,
5. write the new position into the storage file.